# Related rates question on rocket

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I am trying to solve this question. A rocket is flying horizontally at 30 m/sec. How fast is the angle of elevation changing when the horizontal distance from the rocket is 90 meters?

I got an equation $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\cos^2(\theta)$. Now, how to find the value of $\cos^2(\theta)$?

Comment: What is the θ at the instant at which the rate of change of angle has to be found out?

Comment: Yes. That's true.